# Write a C program that counts the number of 1s in the binary representation of an unsigned integer value (4 bytes)

Tags: c, binary

I'm trying to write a C program that will count all of the number of 1s in any binary representation of an integer that the user chooses and inputs. Then I want to print the total number of 1s. But first, I have to check to make sure the inputed number is an integer. My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num;
    int count;
    float input;

    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%f", &input);

    num = (int)input;
    if (num == input) {
        while (num > 0) {
            count += num & 1;
            num >>= 1;
            printf("%d", &count);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Warning: this is not a valid integer.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, I'm able to enter my integer of choice, but then I'm getting an output that says: `134148802013414880201341488020`, or something similar. I've only recently started coding with C, so I'm not sure what this means or where my code is going wrong.

Comment: Suggest to use `unsigned u; scanf("%u", &u);` and then count the `1`s in `u`.

Comment: `int count; ...printf("%d", &count);` should generate a compiler warning.  Save time vs posting on SO.  Enable all compiler warnings to see code is attempting to print the address of `count` and not the value of `count`.

Comment: @Frankie_C what is C++ in this code?

Comment: `%f` is definitely wrong.  Use `%u` as @chux said

Comment: @axiac Sorry confused threads. I was supposed to correct another thread. Put back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `count` variable is not initialized, so it could start from any value at random<sup>1</sup>. Always initialized your variables:

```
int count = 0;
```

Then when you print it, you print the wrong thing - a pointer to count rather than the count itself, and without a carriage return, so you get it all on a line: if the numbers were correct you'd get a single issue of "12345" or "11122234445".

```
printf("Count is now is %d\n", count);
```

I'd strongly suggest you turn on **all warnings from your compiler** - this would have warned you of an uninitialized variable and almost certainly of the difference between the %d and what was fed to it (and maybe too the fact you're missing includes for `printf`)

---

<sup>1</sup> perversely, in some controlled development environment memory is zeroed and you'd see no bug. Then you would okay the program for production. The program would run in a performance optimized environment where memory zeroing isn't worth the trouble. *And there the program would start consistently failing*. Since you're beginning, you don't want to pick up bad habits.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked initializing my count. I also think my print statement should be outside of my while loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are problems in your code:

- you should not read the number as a `float`, you loose precision for numbers larger than 23 bits.
- `count` is uninitialized. Even just incrementing it has undefined behavior.
- you should print the number of bits with `printf("%d\n", count);` after the end of the loop.  You currently print the **address** of `count` with an invalid conversion specifier for this type.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int num;

    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    if (scanf("%u", &num) == 1) {
        int count = 0;
        while (num > 0) {
            count += num & 1;
            num >>= 1;
        }
        printf("%d\n", count);
    } else {
        printf("Warning: this is not a valid integer\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- The program is limited to numbers below `UINT_MAX`, typically `4294967295` on current systems. Larger numbers will be handled in an implementation defined way.
- There are more sophisticated ways to count the number of 1 bits in an integers. You can learn about these here: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive

Comment: One quick question: decimal numbers shouldn't be accepted, I think, but when I test the code with a decimal like 7.6, I receive an output instead of my custom warning. Why is that?

Comment: Well, if you want to mention "more sophisticated ways", is worth mentioning that all modern processors/compilers have some flavor of `popcnt()` which inevitably takes incredibly less than any other trick we can come up with. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function

Comment: @GarrettMcClure: `7.6` is parsed by `scanf("%u"` as the integer `7` followed by other characters (`.6`) which are left in the input stream. It is cumbersome to use `scanf()` to perform precise input validation.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana: good point. I have heard that some sophisticated C compilers actually detect naive bit counting algorithms and produce optimal code with `popcnt` or equivalent opcodes. This would be the best approach to optimisation as it favors simplicity and portability at the source level.